# Displaying a message after adding duplicate records in database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, winforms, stored-procedures

I wrote program in C# winforms and SQL server and LINQ to SQL. I use user control instead of form. In my user control, I put 3 textbox, txtStartNumber, txtEndNumber, txtQuantity. user define value of textboxes, when clicked button, it will insert some records according to the value of txtQuantity.

I want to when duplicate number is created, it won't add to database and display message.
how do i do? I must write code in code behind or server side? i must set this in store procedure or trigger?

```
 private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            long  from = Convert.ToInt64(txt_barcode_f.Text);
            long to = Convert.ToInt64(txt_barcode_t.Text);
            long quantity = Convert.ToInt64(to - from);
            int card_Type_ID=Convert.ToInt32(cmb_BracodeType .SelectedValue);
            long[] arrCardNum = new long[(to - from)];

            arrCardNum[0]=from;

            for (long i = from; i < to; i++)
             {
                 for(int j=0; j<(to-from) ;j++)
                 {
                 arrCardNum[j]=from+j;
                 string r = arrCardNum[j].ToString();
                 sp.SaveCards(r, 2, card_Type_ID, SaveDate, 2);
                 }
             }
        }
```

Stored Procedure code.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.SaveCards
@Barcode_Num int
,@Card_Status_ID int 
,@Card_Type_ID int
,@SaveDate varchar(10)
,@Save_User_ID int 


AS

BEGIN 
INSERT INTO [Parking].[dbo].[TBL_Cards]
           ([Barcode_Num]
           ,[Card_Status_ID]
           ,[Card_Type_ID]       
           ,[Save_User_ID])

     VALUES
           (@Barcode_Num
           ,@Card_Status_ID
           ,@Card_Type_ID
           ,@Save_User_ID)


    END
```

Comment: currently when you click the btnsave button where it gets stored in a database or ?.

Answer (score 0):

If you setup your database correctly, any attempt to add a duplicate key will throw an exception. You can catch that exception to see if it's a result of an attempt to add a duplicate key.
For example:

```
try
{
    sp.SaveCards(r, 2, card_Type_ID, SaveDate, 2);
}
catch (SqlException e) 
{
  // Check if exception was raised because of a duplicate key and perform your logic
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  // Any other exceptions raised
}
```

You mentioned LINQ, so I recommend you also read about the **[DuplicateKeyException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.duplicatekeyexception.aspx)** exception.

Comment: how to prevent user to insert duplicate field in the database?

Comment: here, in my code , didn't compare record with previous records that stored in database

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking. This code will give an exception if there is an attempt to add a duplicate field on a field that does not allow duplicates. Why isn't this good enough for you? You can always SELECT before you INSERT to check if the value already exists, but this can cause race conditions in a multi-client application.

Answer (score 0):

if you are storing the data in sql server then, you can create set [PRIMARY KEY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/08/sql-server-%E2%80%93-2008-creating-primary-key-foreign-key-and-default-constraint/) for the for the barcode num columen in the TBL_Cards table . And you can display error message by using [duplicatekeyException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.duplicatekeyexception.aspx) or Use [RAISEERROR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177497%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) in the stored procedure

hope this helps